# Get function of GPIO pin?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm currently trying to build a small webbased interface to my Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins. 
I'm using the built-in Python `RPi.GPIO` library.

The idea is to see the function and the current state of all the GPIO pins - If a pin is `GPIO.OUT` it should show on/off and if the pin is `GPIO.IN` it should measure the input and show that.

I have almost everything in place, except to find out if a pin is setup to to `GPIO.IN` or `GPIO.OUT`.
I've been searching all over this place, Google and whatever I could get my hands on, but with no luck (Mainly finding tutorials that explains how to read from `GPIO.IN` and the state of `GPIO.OUT`).

Is it possible (using the `RPi.GPIO` library) to find out if a pin is `GPIO.IN` or `GPIO.OUT`? And if so - how?

Answer (score 1):

it is just a file in the file system

something like

```
print open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio1/direction").read()
```

you can just ssh in and `ls` the directory to see the files

you could I suppose do something like this

```
class GPIOData:
    directions={}
    def __call__(self,pin,direction=None):
        GPIOData.directions[pin]=direction
        GPIO.setup(pin,direction)
    def getPinDirection(self,pin):
        return GPIOData.directions[pin]
    def __init__(self,*args):
        pass

class GPIOSetup(object):
    __metaclass__ = GPIOData



GPIOSetup(6,7)
print "GOT:",GPIOSetup.getPinDirection(6)
```

Comment: I have been looking in to that solution, but I don't have a `/sys/class/gpio/gpioX` folder in `/sys/class/gpio`... All I have is `export`, `unexport` and `gpiochip0`- That's why I was hoping for a function that cold do the same in the `RPi.GPIO` library.

Comment: try `echo 123 > /sys/class/gpio/export` .... you might need super user (where 123 is the desired gpio123)

Comment: or really ... why are you checking the direction? that may be a more relevant question

Comment: I tried with 8 (Physical pin) and 14 (bcm (I think it's called?) pin) - both gave me `echo: write error: Device or resource busy`... Even though I stopped the webservice that was using the pin.

Comment: Hmm, this is unexpected - I now have both the `gpio8` and `gpio14`folders, but neither of them seem to change when i turn the pin on/off (Tried with a `tail -f gpio8/direction gpio14/direction`, nothing happened). 
I want to know the direction to be able to show in my interface if the pin is setup to be `GPIO.IN` or `GPIO.OUT` :)

Comment: yeah it looks like the gpio interface in that library is doing weird memory things ... you can alter the c code to remember the state and make it accessible I suppose but thats kinda sledgehammery ...  why do you want to expose that? you could just as easily manually track the state ...

Comment: It's a matter of making an webinterface that can control the Pi, so I thought it could be useful to see the current in/out state of the pins. It's mostly in case some other application has set the in/out to something else than my webinterface.